# Why does this code not work (getting a {"error": "Please use POST request"}" error)

Tags: javascript, html, post

http://jsfiddle.net/GNK5d/

A little background information, I can not use css with this webpage due to the server it is being run on so I am attempting to look for a way around this problem with javascript.

Thanks for your help, the code is listed above.

Comment: Also, you need to remove the script tags in the JS portion when putting things on jsfiddle.

Comment: You still have to use a "post" request, like it says. Regardless, what you're trying to do goes beyond with I think jsfiddle is really useful for--can't you just try it locally?! You're running in to issues around how jsfiddle is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `{“error”: “Please use POST request”}` because, as @Kolink rightly pointed out, POST is a method the form can use. The action attribute is for the URL of the page to process your request.

Updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GNK5d/5/) with what I think you're trying to accomplish.

I set the action to a null string, as you do not need the form to actually submit the request to another page. Likewise, I changed your submit button to just a plain-old button.

As far as "I can not use css with this webpage", what's the end-goal here? What are you trying to accomplish overall. The demonstration you set up on the fiddle seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 2):

`POST` should be the `method`, not the `action`. The `action` is the URL of the script that handles the POST data.

Comment: Changing this gives me a {"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0xaf15bec>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0xaf03dac>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}"}

http://jsfiddle.net/GNK5d/4/

Comment: That is something more complicated than can be solved just by looking at an error message. Sorry.